# Search with both Upper and Lowercase

Tags: java, android, realm

```
public class ActivityPS extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PS_DA ps_da = new PS_DA(ActivityPS.this);
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    android.widget.SearchView searchView;
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    AdapterPS adapterPS;
    List<PS> filteredPs;
    RealmResults<PS> psList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ps);
        cast();
        setUpRecycler();
        searchviewSetUp();
    }

    public void searchviewSetUp(){
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
        filteredPs =filter(psList,s);
        if (filteredPs.size()> 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public List<PS> filter (List<PS> psLists,String s){
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        filteredPs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PS psList : psLists){
        final String text = psList.getCommandName().toString().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(s));
            filteredPs.add(psList);
        }
        psList = realm.where(PS.class).contains("commandName",s).findAll();
        adapterPS = new AdapterPS(ActivityPS.this,psList,realm);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityPS.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPS);

        return filteredPs;
    }
}
```

I want to search through my realm DB and I want that my search view isn't sensitive with case of letters. I did this but it shows only lowercase data in result whether insert with lowercase or uppercase. I don't know what should I do...

Comment: I have never worked with Realm, but one general piece of advice I can give you is that if you have the need to do case insensitive searches, then consider just storing all data in lowercase form, and then also searching using lowercase inputs.

Comment: if I store them with .toLowercase mode when i want to show `em with recycler view, it show with lowercase? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just Found it....
I change my code to this and it works.

```
public class ActivityPS extends AppCompatActivity {
private PS_DA ps_da = new PS_DA(ActivityPS.this);
RecyclerView recyclerView;
android.widget.SearchView searchView;
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
AdapterPS adapterPS;
List<PS> filteredPs;
RealmResults<PS> psList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ps);
    cast();
    setUpRecycler();
    searchviewSetUp();
}

public void searchviewSetUp(){
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

   psList = realm.where(PS.class).contains("commandName",s, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
    adapterPS = new AdapterPS(ActivityPS.this,psList,realm);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ActivityPS.this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPS);


    return false;
}
```

That `.Case.INSENSITIVE` did that automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can make `realm DB` search `case insensitive`, add `Case.INSENSITIVE` `boolean` as a third `argument` in the method:

> ```
> public RealmQuery<E> contains(String fieldName, String value, boolean
> > caseSensitive)
> ```
>
> From documentation: All four string predicates i.e. `contains, beginsWith, endsWith, like` have an optional third
>   argument to control case sensitivity: Case.INSENSITIVE and
>   Case.SENSITIVE. The default is Case.SENSITIVE.

```
psList = realm.where(PS.class).contains("commandName",s, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
```

Comment: yes that work. thank you very much.although I find that my self but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make all the results .to lower case, thus what ever u rnter will not be sensitive.